# send by e-mail sheet content

Tags: vba, email

I'm using this code to create an e-mail
however, I would like to send the content that is in the range A5 to B100, like this:
A5 B5
A6 B6
...
A100 B100

what do you suggest?
current code, looks like this:

```
Public Function Sendemail()
On Error GoTo Ende
esubject = "CBP Review for Approval"
sendto = Range("G1") & Range("H1")
ccto = Range("G1")
ebody = "Please see below a" & vbNewLine & Range("A5") & " " & Range("B5") &             vbCrLf & "Best regards" & vbCrLf & "Your Partner"

Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set itm = app.CreateItem(0)

With itm
.Subject = esubject
.To = sendto
.CC = ccto
.Body = ebody
.Display
End With
Set app = Nothing
Set itm = Nothing
```

the way it is now, just writes A5 and B5 but need a loop to write the other ones
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a For loop to build up the body of your message one row at a time. Replace the following line:

```
ebody = "Please see below a" & vbNewLine & Range("A5") & " " & Range("B5") &             vbCrLf & "Best regards" & vbCrLf & "Your Partner"
```

with the following code:

```
ebody = "Please see below a" & vbNewLine

For i = 5 To 100
    If Range("A" & i) <> "" or Range("B" & i) <> "" Then
        ebody = ebody & Range("A" & i) & " " & Range("B" & i) & vbCrLf
    End If
Next i

ebody = ebody & "Best regards" & vbCrLf & "Your Partner"
```

Note the two different uses of concatenation (`&` operator), one to add new lines to the existing body:

```
ebody = ebody & "more text to add..."
```

and another to create the cell reference on each line. `Range("A" & i)` inside the loop will result in cells A5 to A100 (and similarly B5 to B100) to be added to the message.

Finally, the If statement will make sure that only rows that have data in either cell A or B will be added to your email.

Comment: many thanks!!! it works fine. Just now I have lots of empty lines on the e-mail. how do I copy just the cells that have content?

Comment: @PaulaSimoes Add an If statement inside the loop. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote out the answer, but your questions states you already know what you have to do.  Why not just look it up?  First result from [google search "vba loop"](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html)

Can use UsedRange.Rows.Count to get last row.  If your loop is beyond your range of data, or has blanks, you'll want to uncomment the if statement.  So you don't end up with a bunch of newlines.

```
Dim sData as string

For iRowCounter = 5 to ??
    'if Range("A" & iRowCounter) <> "" or Range("B" & iRowCounter) <> "" then
        sData = sData & Range("A" & iRowCounter) & " " & Range("B" & iRowCounter) & vbNewline
    'end if
Next

eBody = "Please see..." & vbnewline & sData & "Best Regards..."
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm really new to VBA and it was not working properly :(

Comment: Added the code, but there is tons of material that explain how to do this.